# How to substring long nsstrings and present them in uitextview?

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextview, text-files, large-files

I am reading in 2-5 mb large txt files into nsstrings that I want to present in a uitextview.

Now I have experienced that it takes too long to read in the whole string especially since I am removing line breaks every time.

So I have decided separate the `NSString` into individual pages that I can navigate by two buttons ("previous" and "next"). The first thing I did was to decide to separate the `NSString` into 500 characters long substrings (then I remove line breaks before I present the string).

Now this works great and is fast enough, but there is one little problem that annoys me, the last word in the substring that is presented oftentimes gets cut off in the middle.

So what I did then was instead of using 500 characters to separate the substrings, to use 20 dots/periods ". ". This turned out to work very good also until I realized that not all txt files and texts that might be loaded will contain dots/periods because some languages might not have dots.

So I am looking for a solution where I can separate long text files into smaller substrings, about a page long, that I can navigate and that do not cut off the last word in the the substring in half. Any help would be appreciated.

Also I should add that I have tried to separate after x number words (i.e. x number white spaces) which I think might be the best solution but I cannot think of any other way but `componentsSeparatedByString:@". "` which takes to long because it goes through the whole string.

Is there some good way of enumerating a string but that still allows be to navigate through pages, perhaps by saving the substring range location or something?

Comment: can you provide snippet of how your creating the strings form your large file?

Answer (score 0):

Store all your data in a NSMutableArray, then enumerate by sentences in your string and add to a mutable array.

```
NSString * string = @"YOUR VERY LONG FILE";

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);

[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:range options:NSStringEnumerationBySentences usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
   NSLog(@"substring: %@", substring);
   NSLog(@"substringRange len:%lu, loc:%lu", substringRange.length, substringRange.location);
   NSLog(@"enclosingRange len:%lu loc:%lu",enclosingRange.length, enclosingRange.location);

   [array addObject:substring];
        }];
```

Also take a look at other NSStringEnumeration options like ByLines, ByParagraphs or ByWords.